# Firebase token.email_verified going weird

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Ok so im making a blog which requires users to login through firebase. To post comments, their email has to be verified

I know how to verify the email, and i did so with my test account. When i typed into the console

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified
```

it returned true, so yes my email was verified.

But the comment `.validate` rule requires the user to be validated, like so:

```
auth.token.email_verified === true
```

However it wasn't working, so i removed it and it began to work again

After a bit of reading, I realized that i had to

```
const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  user.email, password);

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials)
  .then(() => { /* ... */ });
```

And that makes it work perfectly. The explanation was it apparantly takes the firebase server some time to update its backend validation, but reauthenticating forces the update immediately.

However, I am stumped on how to ask the user to reauthenticate themselves, as i have the following problem

How do I know when the users is validated (`firebase.auth().currentUser.emailValidated`), and at the same time the firebase backend is not updated (`auth.token.email_verified === true` is false) so that i can update my UI and prompt the user to reauthenticate

Basically how can i know when `auth.token.email_verified === true` is not updated yet on the client side

**edit** also is there a client side solution without reauthentication that updates the backend validation?

**edit** I tried `user.reload().then(() => window.location.replace('/'))` but it didnt work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what is likely happening:

`firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified` is updated when `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()` is called after verification. However `auth.token.email_verified` gets its value from the ID token which will not get updated until it gets expired or you force refresh. So you may have to call `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` to force refresh to update the token claim which is sent to the Firebase Database backend.

Comment: Yikes...more messy code, brought to you by Firebase.

Comment: Why can't Firebase do the update automatically when the user click the Verification link? This has caused me a few days just to figure out what went wrong with both my code and security rules. After so many trials and error then only I realised that it is the F*&#@+-~ email not verified, even though it was verified long before that!!!

Comment: I'm using these lines of code for some time in my app, only recently this stopped being reliable. Most of the times I'l get a permission error. Even if I wait 10s between the force refresh and a firestore update, I get 90% of the time a permission error on the auth.token.email_verified rule (as it isnot updated yet) . Anyone else having this problem?