# Firebase firestore not updating email verification status

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have my security rules setup like so (in firestore console).

```
    service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email_verified;
      allow write: if false; 
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase auto logs-in new users. 
Therefore, a recent user will have a non verified email address.

When the user verifies their email, I'm getting these results in my app.

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified // This is true
```

But when I make a request to the firestore I'm getting an error back that says that the user doesn't have enough permission to access that data.

When I sign the user out and then sign them back in, everything works fine.

My initial thoughts are that maybe there is a token that is not refreshed ? 
But this seems extremely confusing because I already refreshed the current user before attempting to make the request to firestore.

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()
```

---

I feel like I'm missing something.

Why are user's forced logged-in after they signup but then their email verification status isn't updated accordingly ?

Do we have to request-reauthentication ?

If so, what was the point of force log-in ?

---

This is getting extremely frustrating because I don't know how I'm suppose to manage my users.

Is signing in unverified user's something that we should do ? 
Wouldn't this lead to security concerns like user's making fake accounts and spamming your application.

---

**Update**

I read [this non swift response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281903/3366784) which re-enforces my suspicion.

I'm going to test this solution tomorrow, the swift version of it is:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(forceRefresh: , completion: )
```

> Docs for the method:
>
> Retrieves the Firebase authentication token, possibly refreshing it if
>   it has expired. Remark
>
> The authentication token will be refreshed (by making a network
>   request) if it has expired, or if `forceRefresh` is YES.

I'm guessing that in my case I have to force refresh because the token will not be expired.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the token has to be refreshed as mentioned in the update above.

Here is how I solved my issue.

First I refresh the auth token

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true)
```

If that was successful, I then refresh the user.

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()
```

My issue was that I thought that reloading the user will refresh the token, I didn't imagine that things could be out of sync.

When I checked if the email was verified I got `true` but the firestore database needs a refreshed token for it to know that the email was verified.

Comment: Hey! I have exactly the same issue and I've tried to apply your solution but for some reason, it doesn't work - still have email_verified = false in the rules. Can you please provide the Firebase SDK version you use? Thanks.

Comment: @VadimSanko Yes, it's `4.10.0`.
Make sure that you don't have a threading issue. I can share my code if you need it or better yet you can share your code.

Comment: @VadimSanko The `getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true)` method has a completion handler that is called a background thread, you need to dispatch the `currentUser?.reload()` method on the main thread. If you don't do that your current user might still be false because it's being refreshed on a background thread.

Comment: I have [the next code](https://iswift.org/playground?QjZ3mq&v=3). How can I run reload on the main thread?

Comment: It still doesn't work for me... Could you please share your piece of code around this issue?

Comment: @VadimSanko The code that you call inside of the update user completion handler should also be called on the main thread. My code is exactly the same, I'm guess it's a threading issue. `Thread.isMainThread` print that to see what thread you are in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173452/discussion-between-vadim-sanko-and-3366784).

Comment: I confirm this solution does not work for me. I use the Flutter runtime, calling user.getIdTokenResult(true); and reload when the user has verified his email adds the email_verified claim to the token, but when requesting the firestore collection access, with a rule checking request.auth.token.email_verified == true, the request is denied. The only solution I have found is to remove the security check. It looks like a bug in Firestore.