# Firebase - event after email verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an issue that when user clicks in the verification link, the popup appears and everything goes well. However if user is logged in, the state is not being updated.

Im displaying a huge banner with text: **Your email is not verified yet**

But still after verifying the mail it still appears, because:

```
fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
```

is not being fired.

Is there a way to listen to verification event, so I can update the app after?

Comment: Email verification happens out of band, so `onAuthStateChanged` is not automatically called. You cannot really detect it synchronously, but there are some workarounds mostly by forcing a token refresh at the right moment. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900115, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900115, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509219, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594760

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you have this section of code. 
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {});

I would try to put it in the constructor of the firebase model(if you have a class for that).
OR 
right after you do firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Usually this will be put in at the entry point of the app.

Comment: It still doesnt get called when email was verified :(((

Comment: How and where are you doing the email verfication?