# context.auth.token.email_verified in https callable Firebase function is false despite verification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to prevent users with an unverified email from executing a cloud function.
My function looks like this :

```
export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.auth && context.auth.token.email_verified) {
    //my actual function code
  } else {
    if (!context.auth) {
      functions.logger.log("unauthenticated call to myFunction");
    } else if (!context.auth.token.email_verified) {
      functions.logger.log("unverified email call to myFunction with token", context.auth.token);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm calling this function from my react-native frontend app this way :

```
const myFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("myFunction");
myFunction(payload);
```

I went through the email verification process by clicking the link I received, and everything seemed to work fine. If I log my current user from my frontend app, the `emailVerified` prop is `true` :

```
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)
```

However, when calling the cloud function, it logs `unverified email call to myFunction with token`, and the `email_verified` prop is `false` inside the token

Am I missing something ? How can the two be different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem comes from token refreshing and is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281903/6353365

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering !
I tried to log the currrent user the way you suggested, and the emailVerified prop is true there too.
Since the email is verified before the call to `myFunction`,  the result should be the same even if I check my current user before the promise resolves, no ?

Comment: Yes you are right the logging inside `then` is irrelevant. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281903/6353365) answer?

Comment: I just checked this answer and tried it, and it is working after refreshing !
I also tried calling the function before refreshing with the account I verified yesterday, and it was working which means it was indeed the outdated token which was causing the issue.
Thank you for linking this answer, I did not find it by myself.
Can I mark this question as duplicate ?

Comment: Sure! I've edited my answer to avoid misleading future readers